# Unable to start RCP Eclipse 4.4.2 application with Java 1.8 on Linux x86_64

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have a RCP eclipse plugin based UI console developed in Eclipse 3.7.2 with Java 1.7. We are porting it to Eclipse 4.4.2 with Java 1.8. We are unable to start the RCP Eclipse 4.4.2 application with Java 1.8 on Linux x86_64. When we try to launch the application, the application crashes after display of splash screen with a pop-up saying that a log is created. Please find below a snippet of log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-04 21:27:59.594
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.biz.client.ui (66).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (93).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (93).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-04 21:27:59.601
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.biz.client.ui was unable to load class com.biz.om.infra.client.ui.rcp.BLWorkbenchApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.biz.client.ui (66).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (93).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError cannot be found by org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more
```

Realizing that it is probably looking for platform specific swt jar file, I downloaded the 4.4.2 delta pack and copied the file: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar into plugins folder. But now I see the above message and also following additional message in log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2015-06-04 21:29:39.347
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 [137]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
```

The launcher file being used is given below:

```
-data
@noDefault
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
/opt/biz/server/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.parentClassloader=ext
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true
-Djava.library.path=/opt/bmc/biz/server/lib
-Dblx.cmrootdir=/opt/bmc/biz/server/br
-Dblx.cmlibdir=/opt/bmc/biz/server/CM/rcp/plugins/com.biz.client.jars_1.0.0/lib
-Xms512m
-Xmx768m
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom
-Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.biz/8.7.00.135
```

It is configured to build and run on Windows 32-bit, Windows 64-bit, Linux x86, Linux x86_64 and Solaris. The biz.product file has following entries about Linux

```
<launcherArgs>
    <programArgsLin>
        -showsplash
        org.eclipse.platform    
        -vm
        /usr/nsh/br/java/bin/java
    </programArgsLin>
    <vmArgsLin>
        -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8  
        -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true      
        -Djava.library.path=/usr/nsh/bin:/usr/nsh/sbin:/usr/nsh/lib
        -Dblx.cmrootdir=/usr/nsh/br
        -Dblx.cmlibdir=/usr/nsh/br/stdlib
        -Xms256m
        -Xmx512m
    </vmArgsLin>
</launcherArgs>
```

I am unable to figure out why the requirement is not being resolved even after addition of the required jar file.

Have anyone faced this problem? Can you please share any suggestions/comments/inputs to troubleshoot/fix it?

Thanks,
Shashi

Comment: When you built the RCP did you specify that it was for Linux / GTK / 64 bit? You must do a build for each combination that you want to use.

Comment: Yes. It is configured to build and run on Windows 32-bit, Windows 64-bit, Linux x86, Linux x86_64 and Solaris. It successfully worked prior to Java 1.8 and Eclipse 4.4.2 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2015-06-04 21:29:39.347
>   !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 [137]
>    Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"

The module `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64` is a *fragment bundle*, it adds the platform-dependent implementation to the SWT bundle. This fragment cannot be resolved when it's host bundle (named `org.eclipse.swt`) is either missing or has the wrong version.

Comment: The file `org.eclipse.swt_3.103.2.v20150203-1313.jar` is already present in the plugins directory. I just added `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar` wondering if it is unable to locate some platform specific implementation.

Comment: Maybe the swt bundle is not in the RESOLVED state for another reason?

Comment: can you please suggest a way to check the state of the jar? Any ideas about when a bundle could be in state other than RESOLVED and what could be done to change that? Any input/pointer would be really very helpful.

Comment: Does the log file also contain an entry for swt itself, starting with `!ENTRY org.eclipse.swt_`?

Answer (score 0):

The application started loading on Linux once following plugins were added to the .product file:

```
  <plugin id="com.<<our-product>>" fragment=""/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>   
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86" fragment="true"/>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case and same errors. My solution is to change the plugin.xml by adding below tow lines in the manifest.mf file,

Require-Bundle: 
 org.eclipse.equinox.ds,
 org.eclipse.help.webapp

hopes that helps.